# Empty White Blank space under root CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-coordinatorlayout

There is a blank space estimated 56dp under the CoordinatorLayout(root) like this in the picture. However this only occurs when there is a AppbarLayout from troubleshooting.

[image]

I don't know how to fix it i tried `fitSystemWindows="true"` but that does not work. Why does it do this? (If i do not make sense please say)

Here is my layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorS50Alpha"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:fillViewport="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/lvProfilePosts"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tbProfiletabs"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tbProfiletabs"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tbProfiletabs"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="283dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorS50Alpha"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout5"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorSearch">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Left" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Center" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivProfileBackphoto"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="320dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_signinandregister"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                    app:srcCompat="@color/colorProfileBack" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shadow_profile_01"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivProfileBackphoto"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

                </RelativeLayout>

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivProfilephoto"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivProfileBackphoto"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.361" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:text="Foster The People"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivProfileBackphoto"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivProfilephoto"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:text="I like bacon and cheese sandwiches"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivProfileBackphoto"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvName"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivAddFriend"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout5"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/ivProfilephoto"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.418"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/addfriend02" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRemoveFriend"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout5"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/ivProfilephoto"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.418"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/removefriend02" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

---

I don't know how to elaborate further than this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is because of wrong positioning of nestedScrollview

Comment: Why you put `ScrollView` inside `NestedScrollView` and then again a `RecyclerView` ? 3 Scrollable children . Your layout seems quite messed up.

Comment: @ADM I have been having this problem for days, when there is no `ScrollView` and no `NestedScrollVIew`, The `AppbarLayout` doesn't stay at the top. Even though its not in the same layout(`ConstraintLayout`) when i scroll the `ToolBar` does not stay in the fixed position instead it feels as if it is apart of the `ScrollView`.

Comment: For your problem try to use `NestedScrollView` with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and remove the `ScrollView` from inside. See if it works. Thx

Comment: @ADM It didn't work. I'm still getting the same problem. If you can write a layout with a toolBar and with a working RecyclerView that does not get the same problem that I'm getting, I would be very thankful. I have just been at this problem for 2 days now and i just want to move on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your layout is fine . its your image which is of specific height . try to test layout by setting background colors to views to see their boundaries.

Comment: I have, I made the `CoordinatorLayout` green and the views red, blue and yellow. But it is still white, meaning that there is something under the `CoordinatorLayout` Hence the title of this question is Empty White Blank space under root CoordinatorLayout. Its a pain in the ass trying to get rid of that blank space

Answer (score 0):

Set

`android:fillViewport="false"` to `true`
in Scrollview

and delete this one

```
 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

if u don't want to scroll toolbar along with scrollview.